# How to use @Description (in allure reporting) dynamically for each test case that executes same test method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, reporting, allure, testng-dataprovider

I am using Allure reporting for my java-selenium testing framework .
My Data provider is a HashMap in form of below

```
public static HashMap<String, String>[][] getDataTable(String fileName, String sheetName)
```

where **fileName** is the **excel workBook name** as saved in the location and **sheet name** is the **one of the worksheet** of workBook.

If I use @Description above the test method then same description will be shown for each test cases.

I have different test cases and their respective description for same test methods 
 (Lets say method is **Login** and  **TestCase1**: Login without password,**TestCase2**:Login without userName)

So for both test case i need different description using @Description in the allure reporting.

Should i modify the data provider for it? If so how?

Comment: did you get any solution.?

Comment: Nope :( didnt get any solutions yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I'm using something like this:

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "getListOfCredentials", dataProviderClass = AuthenticationDataProvider.class)
    public void loginUser(AuthenticationData authenticationData) {
            AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
            lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName("Test wrong login with username: "+authenticationData.getUsername()));
            lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setDescription("Test wrong login with password: "+authenticationData.getPassword()));
}
```

So, I have the Allure description and test title dynamic based on what credentials my data provider method will return each time the test will run using the object authenticationData.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked like a charm.
 Can I please have some references where in I can see what all other features does AllureLifecycle provides?

Comment: Guide me to some reference, need to add dynamic test steps as well. Thinking to use AllureLifecycle . How it can be done?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately, I don't have a good reference for this. I was struggling myself to find this solution and I played around with the code and also looked in the code behind allure and lifecycle in java. I will post below a solution for step dynamically. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically step in Allure I had implemented something like this.
So, my steps for the test case are present in the Page class and are called from my test method.

```
   public class AuthenticationPage extends Page {

   //// Locators

   @Step("Login in app with wrong credentials")
    public void loginInAppExpectFailure(AuthenticationData authenticationData) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        loginUserInApp(authenticationData);
        AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
        lifecycle.updateStep(testStep -> testStep.setName("Step title login with username: "+authenticationData.getUsername()));
    }
}
```

Each time I call the step I update the default name of the step. Lifecycle is using an object of StepResult (in my case testStep is the object) from Allure from which you can manipulate the step properties. You have methods like setStatus, setAttachments etc. Just play around with the method.